# ReturnForAnyArgs without using NSubstitute

Tags: mocking, asp.net-identity, owin, nsubstitute

I am unit testing a Post method that in its implementation uses a

```
 Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager
```

because SignInManager inherit from a class and not an interface I cannot use NSubstitute to mock the SignInManager object. Therefore I cannot use the ReturnForAnyArgs method to get it to return a SignInStatus of say Success.

Is there any way of returning for any arguments without using NSubstitute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SignInManager` has some virtual methods, which NSubstitute will be able to mock (keeping in mind that some real code will execute because it is a class with some non-virtual members). Or you could wrap the features you need from `SignInManager` with your own interface, mock that in tests, and use an adapter class to provide an implementation that uses `SignInManager` under the hood.

I also found [some info on mocking custom sign-in stuff](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Custom-Database-and-OWIN/) under the "Use in a Controller" heading that may help.

Comment: We used this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/342082/Understanding-and-Implementing-the-Adapter-Pattern to create an ISignInManager and  an adapter class that implements it.